# Write html in js with function

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-error

I have got a problem with innerHTML and `onclick`...

I received this error: **Unexpected Syntax Error: missing ) after arguments list**

The problem is :

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
let a, b;

function addDivs(){
  a = 5;
  b = 7;
  parent.innerHTML += "<div onclick='callFunc("+a+","+b+")'></div>";
}

function callFunc(x, y){
  console.log(x+y);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet does nothing, please fix your sample. (Probably call `addDivs` or add a way to call it).

Comment: Plus, if I were you, I would switch simple quotes and double quotes: HTML expects double quotes, not single ones.

Comment: @sjahan HTML allows either, and even *no* quotes in limited cases!

Comment: @deceze I wasn't aware of it :D nice to know!

Comment: Works fine as is when I `addDivs()`. Here's a version that avoids inline code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/dv2wmner/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your posted code is not attaching the click event that calls `addDivs()` to the parent `div`, when you fix it all goes right, attach the event using `addEventListener()` like :

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
let a, b;

parent.addEventListener('click', addDivs, false);

function addDivs() {
  a = 5;
  b = 7;
  parent.innerHTML += "<div onclick='callFunc(" + a + "," + b + ")'>NEW DIV</div>";
}

function callFunc(x, y) {
  console.log(x + y);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">PARENT DIV</div>
```